# Connection string updated on server when publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

i'm trying to get my connection string values updated on production server during publish. I'm trying the following with no results:

```
<connectionStrings>
add name="DataConnect" connectionString="Server=Pepe;Database=Oyeti;Integrated Security=SSPI;" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
```

and also added the xdt:Locator, but i don't think it's the correct way:

```
<connectionStrings>
add name="DataConnect" connectionString="Server=Pepe;Database=Oyeti;Integrated Security=SSPI;" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

What i'm not seeing there?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `<connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)` attributes to the connectionString tag in your transformation file (Web.Release.config) to transform the values in your primary config file (Web.config). As an alternative, you can also specify connection strings in your publish profile.

> Although the default transform file contains an example that shows how
>   to update a connection string, in most cases you do not need to set up
>   connection string transformations, because you can specify connection
>   strings in the publish profile. You'll do that in the deploy to IIS
>   and deploy to production tutorials.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations